# Why error "X3666 cs_4_0 does not support types UAVs", when using cs_5_0 in code and environment?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, hlsl, compute-shader

I'm trying to compile a Compute Shader by replicating the example from this video.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/gclassy/DirectCompute-Lecture-Series-120-Basics-of-DirectCompute-Application-Development

I'm getting the following error message while compiling:

```
Error X3666    cs_4_0 does not support typed UAVs
```

Where is this error coming from? The configuration is cs_5_0 (in code an in VS2019). Here is the compile section of the code.

```
HRESULT DirectCompute::CreateShaders()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    ID3DBlob* CS, * csError;

    hr = D3DCompileFromFile(L"ComputeShader.hlsl", NULL, NULL, "main", "cs_5_0", NULL, NULL,
        &CS, &csError);

    if (csError) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed compiling computer shader", L"Error", MB_OK);
        csError->Release();
    }

    hr = device->CreateComputeShader(
        CS->GetBufferPointer(),
        CS->GetBufferSize(),
        NULL,
        pComputeShader.GetAddressOf());

    context->CSSetShader(pComputeShader.Get(), NULL, 0);
    context->CSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, pConstantBuffer.GetAddressOf());

    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* aSRViews[2] = { pBufferA_SRV.Get(), pBufferB_SRV.Get() };
    context->CSSetShaderResources(0, 2, aSRViews);

    ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* aUAViews[1] = { pBufferOut_UAV.Get() };
    context->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, aUAViews, NULL);


    context->Dispatch(matB_width, matA_height, 1);

    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* aSRViewsNULL[1] = { NULL };
    context->CSSetShaderResources(0, 1, aSRViewsNULL);

    ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* aUAViewsNULL[1] = { NULL };
    context->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, aUAViewsNULL, NULL);

    return hr;
}
```

No error if the RWBuffer reference in the shader is removed.

```
cbuffer SampleCB: register(b0)
{
    uint WidthA;
    uint HeightA;
    uint WidthB;
    uint HeightB;
    uint WidthOut;
    uint HeightOut;
};

struct SimpleBufType
{
    float val;
};

StructuredBuffer<SimpleBufType> MatrixA : register(t0);
Buffer<float> MatrixB: register(t1);

RWBuffer<float> Output : register(u0); //compiles if this is removed (as well as the output below)


[numthreads(1, 1, 1)]
void main( uint3 DTid : SV_DispatchThreadID )
{
    if (DTid.x < WidthB && DTid.y < HeightA)
    {
        float sum = 0;

        for (uint i = 0; i != WidthA; i++)
        {
            uint addrA = DTid.y * WidthA + i;
            uint addrB = DTid.x + i * WidthB;

            sum += MatrixA[addrA].val * MatrixB[addrB];
        }
        Output[DTid.y * WidthOut + DTid.x] = sum;
    }
}
```

Visual Studio is configured correctly I believe, I can use shaders 5.0 in another program.

[image: Visual Studio 2019 Settings]

Any idea what is causing the error? How to ensure the ComputeShader is defined as a cs_5_0 shader?

Comment: [`CheckFormatSupport`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11device-checkformatsupport) check the support of format if the format can be used for an unordered access view.

Comment: Do you mean the format of the UAV view Desc? DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT pretty sure it is supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switched the `RWBuffer` for`RWStructuredBuffer` and it works

Still looking for indication about the error message and what is causing the issue with RWBuffer.

Comment: if this does work for you, please feel free to mark yourself for the people with same issue, and you could accept again if there is any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on a shader and go to properties, you can set the shader version specifically for that shader. I just had the same issue. My compute shader was set to version 4 and I switched it to 5 and everything compiled. I don't know why it doesn't use the VS configuration.